# How to create fetch request Template with compound predicate using .xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to create fetch request template using Predicate with AND / OR condition in my Entity attribute. But I am not getting both option ANY / ALL option enabled for a predicate.[image]

In this I want to make (state == 1 OR state == 2 OR state == 4) AND (dueDate <= $START_DATE AND dueDate >= $END_DATE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ALL` together with three expressions:

[image: Data Model Editor Fetch Image]

Comment: thanks for such a nice suggestion, I have already implemented it in quite similar way with 2 expression. but waiting for a better solution. Will mark it as answer, if this is the only approach :)